# Executing command on Post Build Event for entire solution

Tags: visual-studio, cmd, visual-studio-2015

I know you can execute a post build command for seperate projects in the solution. But how can i set one up for when the entire solution builds successfully?

Comment: Consider creating a MSBuild project.  This will allow you to list all your projects declaratively.  You then declare Targets for building your projects as well as Targets for other tasks like copying and deleting files, etc.  MSBuild, though native to the .Net Framework can be a world of its own.  Here's a msdn walkthrough article [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576348.aspx).  Go through it incrementally and it should help you with what you are looking to do.